# calling a hosted Filemaker Application from a .net program

Tags: c#, filemaker, hosted-app

In my c# application, I am trying to generically open a filemaker application that is hosted on the filemaker server assuming my c# application executes from the server that hosts the filemaker server.  Currently it seems the only way I can do this is to open a generic fmp12 file that contains an External Data Source with the name "Open", type Filemaker, Details "fmnet:/fmserv/Open" where "fmserv" is the filemaker server hardcoded, along with a script trigger to Open File ["Open"]

First, is there any better way to do this programmatically in c# other than just opening this shell filemaker program?  I may need to do this for over 20 different locations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the `fmp://` URL protocol. You can just call it as if it were a web URL, but FileMaker Pro registers to handle all `fmp://` calls. You would use it in the format `fmp://server.ip.address.or.dns.name/filemakerDatabaseName`.

You can even use it to call scripts and send parameters/variables to your database. See http://www.filemaker.com/help/12/fmp/html/sharing_data.16.7.html for more information.

Comment: Thanks so much, it worked as desired.  I ended up using the following code to make this work:


            string fmser = getfmserver();

            string fmip = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(fmser).AddressList[0].ToString();

            string fmURL = @"fmp://" + fmip + @"/Open.fmp12";

            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(fmURL);

* Note, getfmserver() is my function to parse servername from my executable.

Comment: you're welcome, glad it worked! would you mind marking the response as "best answer" and upvoting it? I'm still working on establishing my rep on StackOverflow :-)

Comment: oh well, thanks for trying! Maybe some nice mod will come along and help out.